# One string shared by multiple files

Tags: java, android, modularity

I am building an Android application that uses a tunnel created by `valet share` command. Every 8 hours, a new URL is generated that allows me to host my SQL server. As of now, every activity has a `private String address` that stores the URL.

I want to modularize my app and make this string either global or easily accessible by all files without changing it in every activity every day.

What is the most modular and efficient Android/java way if doing this?

Answer (score 1):

Be simple - use `SharedPreferences` to store that URL and read from it everytim you need it insteed of field access.

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences

You will have to update url in 1 place. You will even be able to easily update it on runtime (eg with dedicated activity)

Answer (score 0):

simplest solution:

make a classes with a getter and a string for your url.

Instantiate an object of the class in your other classes and use the getter there.

```
public class TunnelString {

    private String url = "80e3a96e.ngrok.io";

    protected String getUrl() {
        return url;
    }
}
```

now in your other class do this:

```
    TunnelString urlTunnel = new TunnelString();
    String url = urlTunnel.getUrl();


    address = "http://" + url;
```